# What is the Difference between binary and ascii buffer in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, buffer, ascii

what is the difference between these two lines of code?

`var binStr = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex').toString('binary');`
and `var asc = Buffer.from(hex, 'hex').toString('ascii');`

```
hex = '4d434750040af215000a00000000000a000000000000000000000029'
```

for more detail check this link [jdoodle.com/a/w51](http://jdoodle.com/a/w51)

but when I am converting it back into hex using this https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html

then **binStr** gives correct output and **asc** gives wrong.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: binary is 8 bits, ascii is 7 bits

Comment: then why https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html this site converting ascii wrong and binary right

Comment: because binary is 8 bits and ascii is 7 bits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690159/is-ascii-code-7-bit-or-8-bit

Comment: p.s. your ascii-to-hex site is nothing to do with node.js and is irrelevant (note, it handles 8bit hex just fine by the way, though doesn't like anything too complex in hex)

Comment: @fuzz's link is good reading ... but for nodejs, [read the fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) which states that *ascii  -For 7-bit ASCII data only. This encoding is fast and **will strip the high bit** if set.* - therefore you'd want *binary* - though that is an alias for `latin1` - however, `latin1` is suitable for binary data